# Get records after integer unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    body TEXT
);
```

And I am trying to get records added after certain timestamp. Here is what try to use:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE time > 1387039688
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE time > 1387039688000
```

But I get ALL the records in the table instead of just ones after the specified time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function to convert a timestamp to a `DATE` value:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE time > FROM_UNIXTIME(1387039688)
```

Comment: That worked. But why? I always thought TIMESTAMP is stored as 32-bit integer and it can be compares as an integer. But here integer is converted to be compared to another integer?

Comment: MySQL recognizes integer literals as dates in the format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` or `YYMMDDHHMMSS` (see [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)) for details.